# How can I turn my wireless laptop into a wifi hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, hotspot

When I am in my room, my phone does not have any signal strength to my router. My laptop is at half signal strength, so I can use the internet just fine on that. Now I want to turn my wireless laptop into a hotspot so my phone can connect to my laptop.

How would I go about doing this?

I attempted the `netsh wlan set hostednetwork` approach in command prompt, however my ICS does not have an internet access. How can I enable internet access on my hostednetwork?

Or perhaps there is an alternative to turn my wireless laptop into a wifi hotspot?

Comment: its called "virtual router"[here](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unless you connect your laptop to a network cable too. Any wifi device can only be a receiver or hotspot at the same time. You cannot connect your laptop to the internet with the same wifi as you set it as hotspot. EDIT: Virtual Router seems to indicate it should be possible. I can't test it right now though.

Comment: Virtual router works to a certain extent, but in my scenario, things are starting to get screwy. My laptop is wirelessly connected to my router. And my phone is wirelessly connected to my laptop. When I choose to use my VPN on my phone, my connection becomes severely unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to add as USB wifi dongle or connect via wire the laptop to a new wireless access point.  If they have different SSID and operate on different channels it could work.